# How to find previous year of "some specific date"

Tags: sql

This is my table

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+
| CompanyName | Companyid | Country |   Year    | Salary |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+
|  Company6   |    111    |  INDIA  | 30-Dec-06 | 295000 |
|  Company1   |    111    |  INDIA  | 30-Dec-07 | NULL   |
|  Company2   |    111    |  INDIA  | 28-Dec-08 | NULL   |
|  Company3   |    111    |  INDIA  | 27-Dec-09 | NULL   |
|  Company4   |    111    |  INDIA  | 02-Jan-11 | 135000 |
|  Company5   |    111    |  INDIA  | 01-Jan-12 | 188000 |
|  Company7   |    111    |  INDIA  | 29-Dec-13 | 296000 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+
```

I want details of whose salary is null and the condition is 
the previous year or next year salary should be not null

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL-Server? Oracle? MySQL? ...?

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: Apart from stating your DBMS, please add the expected output based on your sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the best of information you've provided, I tried my best to the following:

I created my own temp

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
  (
    CompanyName varchar(10)
    , CompanyId int
    , Country varchar(10)
    , [Year] date
    , Salary money
  )
```

then inserted some values (note: i used the company name as the primary key)

```
insert into #temp values
  ('Company1',111,'INDIA','12-30-06',295000),
  ('Company1',111,'INDIA','12-30-07',NULL),
  ('Company2',111,'INDIA','12-28-08',NULL),
  ('Company2',111,'INDIA','12-27-09',NULL),
  ('Company2',111,'INDIA','12-28-10',135000),
  ('Company3',111,'INDIA','01-02-11',135000),
  ('Company4',111,'INDIA','01-01-12',188000),
  ('Company5',111,'INDIA','12-29-13',296000)
```

then have it left joined twice to its self's year - 1 and year + 1

first lets drill down the complexity of left join without the where

```
  SELECT
    *
  FROM #temp AS [payroll]
  LEFT JOIN #temp AS [payrollyearminus]
  ON
     DATEPART(YEAR,[payroll].[Year]) - 1 = DATEPART(YEAR,[payrollyearminus].[Year])
  AND [payroll].CompanyName = [payrollyearminus].CompanyName
  AND [payroll].Salary IS NULL
  AND [payrollyearminus].Salary IS NOT NULL
  LEFT JOIN #temp AS [payrollyearplus]
  ON
     DATEPART(YEAR,[payroll].[Year]) + 1 = DATEPART(YEAR,[payrollyearplus].[Year])
  AND [payroll].CompanyName = [payrollyearplus].CompanyName
  AND [payroll].Salary IS NULL
  AND [payrollyearplus].Salary IS NOT NULL
  /* disabled
  WHERE
      [payrollyearminus].CompanyName IS NOT NULL
      OR [payrollyearplus].CompanyName IS NOT NULL
  */
```

following is the result

[image]

now, enable the WHERE and you'll get those companies who's current year salary IS NULL and previous / year after salary IS NOT NULL

EDIT : 
Modify you results by changing the code below

```
SELECT
  *
FROM #temp AS [payroll]
```

into aliased table specific

```
SELECT
  [payroll].*
FROM #temp AS [payroll]
```

then run the table in text mode

[image]

to have a print like this.

[image]

EDIT : Ok, then I changed my left join, please see new left join logic.

```
SELECT
    [payroll].*
  FROM #temp AS [payroll]
  LEFT JOIN #temp AS [payrollyearminus]
  ON
     DATEPART(YEAR,[payroll].[Year]) - 1 = DATEPART(YEAR,[payrollyearminus].[Year])
  --AND [payroll].CompanyName = [payrollyearminus].CompanyName
  AND [payroll].Salary IS NULL
  AND [payrollyearminus].Salary IS NOT NULL
  LEFT JOIN #temp AS [payrollyearplus]
  ON
     DATEPART(YEAR,[payroll].[Year]) + 1 = DATEPART(YEAR,[payrollyearplus].[Year])
  --AND [payroll].CompanyName = [payrollyearplus].CompanyName
  AND [payroll].Salary IS NULL
  AND [payrollyearplus].Salary IS NOT NULL
  WHERE
      [payrollyearminus].[Year] IS NOT NULL
      OR [payrollyearplus].[Year] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Since you're using product specific functionality (and no dbms specified in question), please tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: ms sql server sir..my apologies

Comment: <pre>This is my table</pre>
Company         id                    year     Salary 
 Company1       111                30-Dec-06      295000 
 Company2       111                 30-Dec-07      NULL 
 Company3       111                  28-Dec-08      NULL  
 Company4       111                  27-Dec-09      NULL  
Company5       111                 02-Jan-10      135000 

my output like this .

Company         id                    year     Salary 
 Company2       111                 30-Dec-07      NULL 
 

salary must be null and previous year or next year salary must be not null

Comment: What are you using? MS Sql, Oracle Sql or My Sql?

Comment: ('Company1',111,'INDIA','12-30-07',NULL),my output like this only not leftouter join ,because previous year 2006 is not null salary this will compare previous and next year salary is not null.

Comment: and this also ('Company2',111,'INDIA','12-27-09',NULL), because 2010 salary is not null

Comment: i've made an edit. Company2 cannot be included because there's no 2010 salary on your example.

Comment: i mentioned your table because your table has 2010 year i forgot to mention 2010 but i need out put like that only

Comment: yeah, kindly see my latest edit for the left join to included Company2 in the result set.

Comment: thanks this query shows the right result....

Comment: I encourage you to mark this my post as answer for the benefit of those who has the same case as you. anyway you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, use `dateadd()` function. 
For example,

```
select dateadd(yy, -1, year) AS PreviousYear from YourtableName
```

You can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

For MySQL, you can use `DATE_ADD()` function.

Comment: CompanyName | Companyid | Country |   Year    | Salary |
+-------------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+|
|  Company1   |    111    |  INDIA  | 30-Dec-07 | NULL   |
|  Company3   |    111    |  INDIA  | 27-Dec-09 | NULL   |  i want out put like this because the salary is null and previous year or next year salary is not null

Comment: @user3679026 you can run my answer, you will get same result

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, i think this is you expected.. and for more info check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d10f/2)

-- Create table

```
Create table #company (CompanyName  varchar(20), Companyid int, Country varchar(10) , yr date,  Salary int)
```

-- insert data

```
insert into #company
VALUES 
('Company6' ,    111    ,  'INDIA'  , '30-Dec-06' , 295000 ),
('Company1'   ,    111    ,  'INDIA'  , '30-Dec-07' , NULL   ),
('Company2'   ,    111    ,  'INDIA'  , '28-Dec-08' , NULL   ),
('Company3'   ,    111    ,  'INDIA'  , '27-Dec-09' , NULL  ) ,
('Company4'   ,    111    ,  'INDIA'  , '02-Jan-11' , 135000) ,
('Company5'   ,    111    ,  'INDIA'  , '01-Jan-12' , 188000) ,
('Company7'   ,    111    ,  'INDIA'  , '29-Dec-13' , 296000) 


-- all data
select * from #company

--Resulted data
select * from #company  where (year(yr)-1) not in (
SELECT year(yr) FROM #company C1 where C1.salary is not null
)
and (year(yr)+1)  not in (
SELECT year(yr) FROM #company C1 where C1.salary is not null
)
and salary is  null
```

Comment: Since you're using product specific functionality (and no dbms specified in question), please tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: ('Company1'   ,    111    ,  'INDIA'  , '30-Dec-07' , NULL   ),

Comment: Company2 111 INDIA 2008-12-28 NULL
Company3 111 INDIA 2009-12-27 NULL

Comment: @user3679026 .. pls check this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d10f/2) ... this is giving rows as expected.. if you still have any problem then post pls